# Silent authentication via PHP when making API-call

Tags: php, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, silent

First time posting, long time reading.
I want to perform a silent authentication against Azure AD but I can't seem to get it to work.

Please find image below which outlines steps and overall solution approach.

[image: Click this link to open an image of the solution overview]

This is the current approach I have set up and it is working quite well:

1. User logs in and is authenticated against a SaaS solution via Azure AD.
2. On the front page within the SaaS solution, user clicks on a widget which opens up a modal window.
3. Ajax call (POST) (bootstrap-table) is made which calls a php-script from another domain.
4. PHP script receives ajax request (CORS settings are ok). **Here is where I would like the script to perform a silent user authentication against Azure AD and return user's email**. It should not in any way display any login-screens or account selection screens. If the authentication fails it should just exit... perhaps with a error message.
5. Once authenticated, php-script performs API call(s)
6. On successfull call, JSON data is returned
7. And JSON returned from PHP-script is displayed on front page (bootstrap-table).

I've been trying with various examples/libraries (thephpleague/oauth2-client, magium/active-directory, ...) and I'm able to authenticate fine via Azure AD App but there is always a login-screen present or select account screen is displayed.

The reason for this approach is that I believe CORS are not secure or perhaps should not be used as a security measure. And also, because some browser does not seem to return Origin I am experiencing some issues...

Now, I'm more of a hobby-developer and perhaps this is in no way possible to achieve but I would like to believe it is and would appreciate any tips/hints on how to perform this silent activity/authentication.

Thank you!